# $\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{\sin z}$ at the origin- Classify singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

I tried for a while to classify the singularities of $\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{\sin z}$ at the origin, but I am stucked

A way to do this it's  to consider a hint of a colleague :

$\sin(z)=z\bigl(1+z^2g(z)\bigr)$ where $g$ is analytic with $g(0)\ne0$.

So
$$\frac1z-\frac1{\sin z}=\frac{\sin z-z}{z\sin z}=\frac{z^3g(z)}{z^2\bigl(1+z^2g(z)\bigr)}.$$

Is anyone could explain to me in details what he did?

Comment: basically, he checks whether this expression has a limit or not, when $z \to 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $z$ close to $0$, $\sin z = z - \frac{z^3}{6} + O(z^4)$.

Thus: $\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{\sin z} = \frac{\sin z - z}{z \sin z} = \frac{-z^3/6+O(z^4)}{z^2-z^4/6 + O(z^5)} = \frac{-z/6+O(z^2)}{1-z^2/2+O(z^3)}$.

When $z \to 0$, the above expression converges to $0$. Thus, $0$ is a removable singularity.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience in the classification of singularities. Could you just explain to me why if it is converge to $0$, so $z_0=0$ would be a removable singularity?

Comment: You have $3$ types of isolated singularity. If there was at least $1$ term whose power is negative (which is the case of essential singularity or pole), say $z^{-n}$, for $n >0$, then when $z \to 0$, $f(z)$ would converge to infinity, which is not the case here. So only removable singularity is valid.